# Why is this integral equal to $\frac{2\sinh(\pi)}{(1+n^2)\pi}$

Tags: integration, proof-explanation

It is true that $$\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^y\cos(ny)dy=\frac{2\sinh(\pi)}{(1+n^2)\pi}$$ but I don't see why. 
Could someone write some intermediate steps please?

Comment: use $\cos(x)=\Re(e^{ix})$

Comment: alternativly integrate by parts two times

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^y\cos(ny)dy=\text{Re}\left(\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{(1+in)y}dy\right)=
\text{Re}\left(\frac{\left[e^{(1+in)y}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}}{1+in}\right).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thanks! . .